# Is there a way to change the /tf in a rosbag?

Tags: rviz, rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a rosbag with a /tf topic containing only static transforms. Is there a way I can alter one of the transforms?

I have tried creating a new filtered rosbag not containing the /tf and generating the /tf from a launch file. But I get issues when trying to display the pointclouds in rviz.

I get the error : "Message removed because it is too old" when trying to display PointCloud2 topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265928/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-/tf-in-a-rosbag?/) by [RachitB11](https://answers.ros.org/users/31095/rachitb11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

Set the param `use_sim_time` true before you start both rviz and rosbag and play your rosbag File using

```
rosbag play --clock <yourfile.bag>
```

This will cause your BAG to publish Sim time and rviz to believe it was lauched at the time the BAG was Recorder.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RachitB11](https://answers.ros.org/users/31095/rachitb11/) on 2017-07-11**:
That works perfectly. Thanks.